# Clear all sessions for web application in tomcat 7

Tags: java, session, tomcat7

I'm trying to update a couple of JAR files after my web application starts and doing a restart for the changes to take effect.(requirement) 
The problem is , the session information is being persisted by tomcat. Yes, I do have a "sessionEventListener" listener in my application, but that shouldn't be a problem IMHO.

I want everything to start afresh from tomcat ( running standalone) , be it sessions, cache, or any information about the web application given to tomcat, except for the WAR file of course.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During development (in Eclipse) I usually use 'Clean Tomcat Work Directory' option found when right clicking on Servers view. That will wipe all session related data.

Comment: Thanks Kennet, but I'm looking to do the same for a standalone tomcat. Have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: There is also an Admin/Manager application, info http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html, that can give you session status (and if I remember correctly clear session data)

Answer (score 3):

In your tomcat 7 context.xml you can add/uncomment this line to clear all sessions on tomcat restart.

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```